# C# Remove characters from string between /**/

Tags: c#

In string will be something like this:

```
for(I=1;I<10;I++) /*Else*/ {A = "for"; B = 'c'; break;} // while(a < 10)
```

I would like to remove from this string anything that is between `/**/` and between `""` and between `''` and anything after `//`

Here is example

input:

```
for(I=1;I<10;I++) /*Else*/ {A = "for"; B = 'c'; break;} // while(a < 10)
```

output:

```
FOR(i=1;i<10;i++) /**/ {a = ""; b = ''; BREAK;} //
```

I know that I have to go through characters in string with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    // search for /**/ ?
}
```

but i don't know how should I remove characters and put the other characters in new string.

```
string sentence = "for(I=1;I<10;I++) /*Else*/ {A = "for"; B = 'c'; break;} // while(a < 10)";
        //how can I remove these characters from string so it will look something like this?
string shortSentence = "FOR(i=1;i<10;i++) /**/ {a = ""; b = ''; BREAK;} //";
```

Comment: what is it specifically you are trying to do..? this question makes no sense in it's current state

Comment: If you dont undestand it there is no need to give it - :)

Comment: i'm trying to remove everything that is between comments and quotes

Comment: Is it a requirement that the /* and */ remain when you are done? Everything is much simpler if you are allowed to remove those as well.

Comment: unfortunately they have to stay

Comment: Why are the lowercase letters in the input changed to uppercase and vice-versa?

Comment: that's just another part of the task.. but for now I want to finish this first :)

Comment: Take a look at my answer. It should solve the first part. Would you like to get a solution for the second part?

Comment: I'm not aloud to use Remove or IndexOf... :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to ignore characters when copying from one string to another - c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41902544/how-to-ignore-characters-when-copying-from-one-string-to-another-c-sharp)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this. The idea is to first remove the stuff at the end, the // comments.  Then afterwards, we search for /* and the next */, remove that text (we are left with `/**/`, save the index of that string and remove it as well. Once we have no more /* strings, we reinsert the `/**/` into the positions we removed them from.

NOTE: This won't work if you have something like this `/* comment /* more comment */ and some other part */`. But this also isn't a valid comment in C#, which is the language you tagged here.

```
 static string s = "for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ var myVar = \"Test\"; /*commented out code*/ Console.WriteLine(\"stuff\"); /* more comments here*/}//my comments here \n var myOverVar = /*more stuff removed*/ true; //some more comments";


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //s.IndexOf()
    var result = new List<string>();
    var lines = s.Split(new[] {"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); //use this if you have multiple code lines, separated by new lines.
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        var listOfPositions = new List<int>();
        var l = line;
        //chop off everything after comments
        var indexOfLineComment = l.IndexOf("//");

        l = l.Remove(indexOfLineComment + 2); // 2 because // is two characters long
                var openBraceIndex = l.IndexOf("/*");
        while (openBraceIndex != -1) //-1 indicates that we didn't find /*
        {
            var closingBraceIndex = l.IndexOf("*/");
            if (closingBraceIndex == -1)
            {
                break; //you didn't specify how to the case when an error in syntax was made, but handle it here
            }
            l = l.Remove(openBraceIndex + 2, closingBraceIndex - openBraceIndex-2);
            var ind = l.IndexOf("/**/");
            listOfPositions.Insert(0, ind);
            l = l.Remove(ind, 4);
            openBraceIndex = l.IndexOf("/*");

        }
        foreach (var i in listOfPositions)
            if (l.Length <= i)
                l = l + "/**/";
            else
                l = l.Insert(i, "/**/");
        result.Add(l);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is very complex and hard to maintain. I would like to suggest you to split it into a few methods (I'm working on it right now).

Comment: But I'm not here to code for the OP. I offered a solution to their problem as an algorithm. It's up to them to implement it correctly, and if they have problems with that, come back and ask here.

Comment: Take a look at my answer for simpler and more maintainable code.

Comment: What if I would just start placing caracters to new string and when I find /* then I skip till */ and then continue placing other caracters. And same thing for //

Comment: You can probably get away with that, you should try and find out. I would however start with the // part first, because you know that everything in there has to be removed. I'm not saying my solution is the most efficient by any means.