# how to ignore characters when copying from one string to another - c#

Tags: c#

How can I ignore characters between /* */ in string when copying to another string?

```
string str1 = "/*TODO:if*/";
```

How to ignore the caracters between /**/ so the new string will look like this:

```
string str2 = "/**/";
```

**I am not allowed to use any library functions!**

Comment: Is it possible you can have something like `"/*TODO:/*if*/"`?

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: The purpose of this assignment is to see how _you_ would solve the problem.  It seems unfair for us to tell you what you would do.

Comment: It's easy.  `string str2 = "/**/";` Tada!

Comment: wow are you magician ? :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "give me the code"

Comment: so what you are saying is that if somebody asks for help when he is stuck at some part of programming he is not aloud to ask for help ? nice mind set :)

Comment: How does it differs from your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41884042/c-sharp-remove-characters-from-string-between

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Remove characters from string between /\*\*/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41884042/c-sharp-remove-characters-from-string-between)

Comment: You have not said where you are stuck or what you have done so far, just posted the problem and asked for a solution.  You state that you cannot use "library functions", which means that the purpose is to see _how_ you approach the problem without just calling a function that does it.  If your approach to solving the problem is to ask strangers on the internet for the answer then you are just cheating yourself.  If you have tried something and are stuck on a particular part _then_ I think it's fair to ask for help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code (it *does not* use any library function):

```
static string FormatString(string str) =>
    RemoveAfter(str, "/*") + SubstringFrom(str, "*/");

static int IndexOf(string str, string value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length - value.Length; i++)
    {
        bool found = true;

        for (int j = 0; j < value.Length; j++)
        {
            if (str[i + j] != value[j])
            {
                found = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (found)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

static int LastIndexOf(string str, string value)
{
    for (int i = str.Length - value.Length; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        bool found = true;

        for (int j = 0; j < value.Length; j++)
        {
            if (str[i + j] != value[j])
            {
                found = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (found)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

static string SubstringFrom(string str, string value)
{
    int startIndex = LastIndexOf(str, value);

    int length = str.Length - startIndex;
    char[] result = new char[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = str[startIndex + i];
    }

    return new string(result);
}

static string RemoveAfter(string str, string value)
{
    int length = IndexOf(str, value) + value.Length;
    char[] result = new char[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = str[i];
    }

    return new string(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string str2 = Regex.Replace(str1, @"/\*.*\*/", "/**/");
```

Using a regular expression, you can capture all instances of `/*[anything]*/` and replace it with just the text you want: `/**/`. However, this will be very greedy. If you have the string `/*foo*/bar/*baz*/`, this will eat all of it.

```
string str2 = Regex.Replace(str1, @"/\*.+?\*/", "/**/");
```

By changing it to be a lazy regex, the string `/**/bar/**/` will be returned.

Given the edit above, this could also be done without Regex by doing a simple index search - though it is a greedy replacement.

```
string str2 = str1.Substring(0, str1.IndexOf("/*")) + "/*" + str1.Substring(str1.LastIndexOf("*/"));
```

This just takes everything before the first `/*` and then everything after the last `*/`.

Comment: Is this possible without using any library function ? :P

Comment: I tried this and it works perfectly but unfortunately I am not aloud to use any library functions

Comment: the Regex will not work with the string for example  "/*TODO:if*/ textToKeep /*TODO:else*/";

Comment: @Damjan25 Check out my answer. It *does not* use any library functions.

Comment: @BobyOneKenobi The lazy regex will work with your textToKeep example, though admittedly, the string substitution method won't work. It's rather greedy.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure it makes sense that you can't use library functions, considering all functions are essentially library functions.   I think the limitation here is that you can't bring in a library that doesn't already come imported in a new project.  That's OK, we can do this hobbled like that. The `Type` `string` has a `Split` function, and failing that we can play it dirty and use indeces like it's 1995.  I didn't get to test these but you should be well on your way with them.  It was a fun little exercise, honestly.

Given : `string str1 = "Stufftokeep/*TODO:if*/StufftokeepAgain";`

```
 string[] crazyHomework = str1.Split('/');
 string result = string.Empty;
 foreach(string s in crazyHomework)
 {
    if(s.IndexOf('*') == -1)
       result += s + " ";  //added a space to keep them separate
 }
```

That gets you there using only `System` functions.   Failing that, you can mutate the `string` into a lovely `array` of `type` `char` (which is all a `string` is anyway).

```
string result = string.Empty;

bool copy = true;
char[] array = str1.ToCharArray()
foreach(char a in array)
{
   int i = array.IndexOf[a];
   if(a == "/" && array.IndexOf(a) != array.Length - 1 
   && 
   (array[a + 1] == '*' || array[a -1] == '*'))
   {
       copy = !copy;
   }
   if(copy)
      result += a.ToString();
}
```

You'll have some space issues on that one if there isn't whitespace in the `string`, though.

Answer (score -1):

Quick and dirty

```
string temp = null;
string str1 = "this shoudl remain/*TODO:if*/*/*testing again */-and so should this";
int x, y;
while ((x = str1.IndexOf("/*")) != -1)
{
    if ((y = str1.IndexOf("*/")) > x)
    {
        temp += str1.Substring(0, x + 2) + str1.Substring(y, 2);
        str1 = str1.Substring(y + 2);
        continue;
    }
    temp += str1.Substring(y, x);
    str1 = str1.Substring(x)
}
temp += str1;
```